# C++ lambda: how to avoid slicing a reference if captured by value

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, c++14

I have a method that takes a parameter which is a reference to a base class and I enqueue invocations of the method body by wrapping the method implementation in a `queue<function<void()>>`

The issue is that I was hoping to capture the method's parameter by value so that each lambda in the queue could then execute with its own copy.

But if I capture by value, the lambda copy of the reference parameter seems to slice it leaving me with a base class copy instead of the actual derived class in the reference.

If I capture the parameter by reference instead, I do get the actual derived classin the lambda but the obj can go out of scope between invocations of the method or its state can change.

Mind you, the method is supposed to be reentrant but not async nor concurrent.

This is an example of what I mean (omitting the queue):

```
struct BaseObj {
    virtual ~BaseObj() = default;
};

struct DerivedObj : public BaseObj {
    
};

void someMethod(BaseObj& obj) {
    
    //  obj is of type BaseObj:
    std::cout << "\nobj type:" << typeid(obj).name();
    
    auto refLambda = [&] {
        //  captured obj is of type DerivedObj:
        std::cout << "\nrefLambda::obj type:" << typeid(obj).name();
    };
    
    auto valLambda = [=] {
        //  captured obj is of type BaseObj:
        //  presumably because it was copied by value, which sliced it.
        std::cout << "\nvalLambda::obj type:" << typeid(obj).name();
    };
    
    refLambda();
    valLambda();
}
```

The output when calling the method like so:

```
DerivedObj obj{};
someMethod(obj);
```

Is:

```
obj type:10DerivedObj
refLambda::obj type:10DerivedObj
valLambda::obj type:7BaseObj
```

As of now the only way I managed to preserve the derived type in method invocations is by:

1. passing a heap allocated object from the calling code.
2. capturing by reference in the lambda.
3. making sure to not mutate the original in the calling code.
4. finally deleting the heap obj after the method returns.

Like this:

```
    DerivedObj* obj = new DerivedObj();
    someMethod(*obj);
    delete obj;
```

But I was hoping to be able to just pass a reference from the calling code stack and be fine even if inside `someMethod` something happens that triggers another call to `someMethod`.

Any ideas?

One approach I thought of but I'm not sure how to do would be, inside `someMethod', moving the parameter to the heap, executing the lambda and then finally deleting it (since the caller won't really use it after calling this method). But not sure if this is actually hacky (I only thought about it because that's a bit like what Objective-C blocks do).

## update:

This is the solution I have so far:

```
void Object::broadcast(Event& event) {
    auto frozenEvent = event.heapClone();
    
    auto dispatchBlock = [=]() {
        for (auto receiver : receivers) {
            receiver.take(event);
        }
        
        delete frozenEvent;
        _private->eventQueue.pop();
        if (!_private->eventQueue.empty()) {
            _private->eventQueue.front()();
        }
    };
    
    _private->eventQueue.push(dispatchBlock);
    if (_private->eventQueue.size() == 1) {
        _private->eventQueue.front()();
    }
}
```

Yes, I know, I'm using raw pointers... (eeeeevil.... :p), but at least I can keep the signature of the method with the ref parameter.

The clone method is along the lines of this:

```
template <class T>
struct ConcreteEvent : public Event {
    virtual Event* heapClone() {
        return new T(*(T*)this);
    }
            
    // .... more stuff.
};
```

Comment: how about make `someMethod` a template method? You can't copy an object without its type. or just pass `shared_ptr` around

Comment: @BryanChen a smart pointer would work but I was trying to avoid it. Same as template methods.

Comment: Please take a look at [C++ Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md). I believe C++ code tagged with C++11 or C++14 should seriously consider using smart pointer instead of naked new and delete.

Comment: @LebenAsa using raw pointers is a matter of choice and in this case just one proposed solution (and which I'm not happy about which is why I am asking the question for alternatives in the first place). Smart pointers are only one more feature of the language (unlike objective-c where they are built into the language) and they are not the right choice in all contexts (i.e. this code will run in a tight render loop). Finally, the 11 and 14 tags are in case the 11 or 14 specifications have some feature to prevent slicing, and not for implying style. Still, point taken :).

Comment: In c++14, you may replace `auto frozenEvent` by `std::unique_ptr<Event>` and then capture by move instead of by value.

Comment: I had already tried my above code (under update) with a unique_ptr instead of a raw point, but I didn't know about the C++14 move semantics in lambdas. Nice!. I just tried it out but it then won't let me enqueue the lambda in my queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem possible to achieve the result you want without some intrusive changes. Currently, you have a caller that changes or destroys its object without caring whether the reference is still in the queue. With this kind oft caller, your only choice is to make a copy. The function that creates the lambda does not know what type of object you are going to pass, so it doesn't know how to copy it.

There are different approached to solve your problem: You can make the caller aware of the extra reference by having it hold a `shared_ptr` and copying the shared pointer into the lambda. This solves the life-time issue, but still depends on the caller to not modify the object. You could also have the compiler generate different enqueueing functions for each derived class by making that function a template. Each instance of the template of the template knows how to copy its specific type. You already dismissed both oft these solutions. There is just one more approach I know of, which is adding a virtual clone function to your base class that you implement in the derived classes to create a heap copy.

Comment: Seem like it. Thanks. I went for the heap copy approach for now (as shown in the update to my question).

Comment: @SaldaVonSchwartz, if you knew the type statically in the caller, you could make the function a template. But otherwise a `clone` method is the only way. You could try using [Boost.Type Erasure](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_typeerasure.html) to handle the cloning (it can handle cloning objects without adding the base class for them, but it is quite a bit of stuff to learn).

Comment: @JanHudec trying to stay clear of Boost since I'm doing this stuff "from scratch" on purpose. But thanks.

Comment: @SaldaVonSchwartz It might be a very educating experience to do everything from scratch, but you should keep in mind that not using smart pointers is contradicting the general trend in C++ development. Especially since we now have unique_ptr which should introduce no overhead over manually using new and delete correctly. If you intend to work on modern C++ projects (whether open-source or for some employer), you should get used to using the tools the standard library provides. Getting to know the most common boost libraries helps, too. Type erasure is not that commonly used, though.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `[=]{}` for your lambda, you can do `[DerivedObj obj=obj](){}` which will capture exactly what you want how you want it.

Answer (score -2):

Use pointer as `someMethod` argument instead:

```
void someMethod(BaseObj* obj) {
    std::cout << "\nobj type:" << typeid(*obj).name();
    auto refLambda = [&] {
        std::cout << "\nrefLambda::obj type:" << typeid(*obj).name();
    };

    auto valLambda = [=] {
        std::cout << "\nvalLambda::obj type:" << typeid(*obj).name();
    };

    refLambda();
    valLambda();
}

int main() {
    DerivedObj obj;
    someMethod(&obj);
}
```

Tested in VS2013 it would print:

```
obj type:struct DerivedObj
refLambda::obj type:struct DerivedObj
valLambda::obj type:struct DerivedObj
```

Comment: If you capture the pointer by value, you get the same result as if you capture the object by reference: You still don't get a copy of the object. So this doesn't answer the question in my oppinion.

Comment: Ah yes. I missed the fact that OP wants to acquire copy for each item in queue.

Comment: I updated my question to show the use case with the queue, as it might further illustrate the problem. As of now I fixed it by having the object in question have a clone method that I use to create a heap version of it for using while inside the method.